# Serve non-production configuration Angular

Tags: angular

I have multiple configurations in my `angular.json` for multiple environments for our application, e.g.

```
"configurations": {
  "apples": {
    ...
    "optimization": true,
    "aot": true,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

```
"serve": {
  "configurations": {
    "apples": {
      "browserTarget": "app-name:build:apples"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to serve these configurations locally without needing all the production level options set such as *aot* and *optimization*. Because it takes the serve 10x as long to reload as would a non-production configuration.

How do I do this without duplication of configurations for **serve** and **build**?

Answer (score 0):

You will want a different build configuration. You can copy the one you use in prod, name it something new, give it a new name, and update the values you need changed.

```
"configurations": {
  "oranges": {
    ...
    "optimization": false,
    "aot": false,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Then you can reference that configuration in your serve configurations.

```
"serve": {
  "configurations": {
    "oranges": {
      "browserTarget": "app-name:build:oranges"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can serve using `ng serve -c oranges`

Hope that helps.